# Windows 10 keeps opening apps on its own

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bug

After the last windows "update" I've been experiencing a lot of problems. First it was ctfmon.exe that didn't work, I couldn't type anything on the search bar. I managed to solve that on my own... But now there's this issue that windows will open random apps on its own while I'm playing. Mostly the calculator.

I tried uninstalling calculator but it doesn't work. it tries to open and then appears a message that I don't have the app and blablabla (but still minimizes the game, so uninstalling it is pointless)

I also tried disabling windows tablet mode and game mode, but still nothing.

Before you ask, yes... I've run antivirus and antimalware. nothing was detected. I'm convinced this is an "update" bug since it started after the last, and browsing in the internet plenty people seem to have experienced similar problems (although not any of them solved)

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  Run in order:   (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  (2) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  (3) SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart when done and test.

Comment: I have yet to see sfc or dism fix anything ever.  I myself have tried to use them countless times with no luck.  Do you have a calculator key on your keyboard?  Are you sure that the apps opening up are not related to your keyboard? *something* is triggering these apps to start up.  There is no logical answer to windows randomly starting up apps due to and update.  Not saying you dont have a real problem.. but I doubt the update is the cause unless it somehow affected an input device.

Comment: I have used DISM and SFC successfully numerous times, although, of course, certainly not every time. So they are worth a try. If no results from these two repairs, a Windows 10 Repair Install would be the next thing to try.

Comment: I tried running the first command you said but it is infinitely stuck at 10%...

Comment: Yeah... It turns out the keyboard was the problem. I changed and now I don't have this problem anymore.I had assumed it was the update since it did mess with other stuff :3

Comment: Yo what did you change? Please answer, I have this problem too.

Comment: Woah I just saw this now, you probably have long solved it. Anyway, I changed the keyboard. I switched it for other. To be fair when I switched the keyboard it worked for a while, but later it started opening apps on its own again.
I brought it to a technician and learned that it was actually the PSU. Yep, it turns out when the PSU can't handle the currents, the computer may start malfunctioning like that for some reason.
Either way, it's most likely a hardware problem.